# What is the wordpress hook when I publish a new post, (not when I update a published one)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I want to send an email any time a new post is FIRST published (not when it is edited)

I tried:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'postPublished');
```

But postPublished is **ALSO called when I update an already published post**.
I just want to get it called **ONLY at first time a post is published**.

Regards

Comment: you can just check the ID of the post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the hook you're looking for is `draft_to_publish`

If you are wanting to only send an email on a new post I would consider targeting when the post is published.  You could even look at the [`transition_post_status`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) hook and just conditionalize if the post has been edited, something like this could work:

```
function so_post_40744782( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        $author = "foobar";
        $message = "We wanted to notify you a new post has been published.";
        wp_mail($author, "New Post Published", $message);
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'so_post_40744782', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This would be where I'd start as well. Here's some more info on it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: @AndyWarren I was just thinking of that as well, and made an edit.

Comment: what are these parameters :  'so_post_40744782', 10, 3 ?

Comment: Priority and accepted arguments, you can read on it [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Answer (score 5):

You should read [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) from the WordPress Codex in order to fully understand the problem.

A possible solution which covers most cases for instance is:

```
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'postPublished');
add_action('future_to_publish', 'postPublished');
add_action('private_to_publish', 'postPublished');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_callback( $post_id, $post  ) {

        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '&action=edit') !== false) {

            //edit previous post
        }
        else{
            //just add a new post
        }
    }
    add_action( 'publish_{your_post_type}', 'your_callback', 10, 3 );
```